# Issue with rake & mysql2 gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, schema, rake, mysql2

Newbie to rails here. I'm running Snow Leopard with 10.6.4 with rails (3.0.7), mysql2 (0.3.2) gem & mysql-5.5.12 (64 bit version). 
My problem is that rake wont dump DB Schema into my rails project. The error it gives:

```
Homes-Mac-Pro:demo home$ rake db:schema:dump
(in /Users/home/Sites/demo)
rake aborted!
dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.2/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.2/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.2/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
/Users/home/Sites/demo/Rakefile:4
```

Full trace can be found [here](http://pastie.org/1986136)

This is my first rails question in Stack overflow. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very common problem. The simple solution is to do the following in your Gemfile.

```
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.2.7' # Not mysql2 version 0.3.2 like you have
gem 'rake', '~> 0.8.7' # Not rake version 0.9.0 like you have
```

[Blog Post](http://chuckjhardy.com/post/5704383770/rails-and-rake-0-9-0-dont-play-nice-together)

Any other versions above these dont work with Rails 3.0.0 - 3.0.8

Let us know how you get on. All the best.

Comment: Thanks for input but unfortunately, installing & listing Mysql2 0.2.7 in my Gemfile isn't working for me. I would use good old mysql gem in my Gemfile but infamous "undefined method `init' for Mysql:Class" is bugging me there too.

Comment: If you are able to run bundle exec rake db:schema:dump and it works (with rake and mysql2 gem version specified) then your system is still trying to use the most upto date version. You need to gem uninstall mysql2 and uninstall all version, do the same with rake and bundle install again. Let us know how you get on.

Comment: Feel free to mark this answer as resolved if you manage to get it with this answer. All the best.